# C# - Can't get reflection to work in my project?

Tags: c#, system.reflection

So this is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
//main.cs
using System;

class Program {
    static string myString = "Hello world";
}
```

```
//example.cs
using System;

public class DoStuff {
   public static void ShowVariable() {
     Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().GetField("_datafile").GetValue(this));
   }
}
```

Desired output:

> Hello world

What do I need to do? I have absolutely no idea. And yes, I have looked at questions on this website for reflection, but I just don't understand it! What can I replace so that whatever I pass in as "_datafile" even if it's a variable as a string (such as username instead of "username"), it will display that variable?

Thank you.

Comment: A moment's thought about what "GetField" means and what the input should be is probably warranted here.  The docs are pretty good at explaining what the string you give it should be.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at this line Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().GetField("_datafile").GetValue(this)); and use Watch to view the fields returned by this.GetType().GetFields();

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right, you want this:

```
public static void ShowVariable() {
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(Program).GetField("myString", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(this));
```

Here the code takes the static `myString` field from the `Program` class.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. After trying, I am getting BindingFlags doesn't exist in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

The GetField method returns a [FieldInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) defined in the Type it's invoked on. The string parameter is the name of the field. So if you have:

```
public string myString = "something";
```

You would invoke

```
GetField("myString");
```

Note that GetField(String) returns only public fields. To get other kinds of fields, you have to use the GetField(String, BindingFlags) method. More about these methods [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This class has nothing to do with 'hello world'.. i think u wanted to check the other class, and even if so, the field name u called is _datafile which is not "myString" which holds the "Hello world"... i'm a little confused..

```
//example.cs
using System;

public class DoStuff {
public static void ShowVariable() {
Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().GetField("_datafile").GetValue(this));


//Desired output:
//Hello world

}

}
```

My example works..

```
 public class DoStuff
    {
        public string _datafile = "hello world";
        public void ShowVariable()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().GetField("_datafile").GetValue(this));


            //Desired output:
            //Hello world

        }

    }

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DoStuff().ShowVariable();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm not passing "datavalue" actually, i'm passing myVar.Substring(1), and that is not working. I am getting the error that it is an object, not a string!

Answer (score 0):

From your question, you are trying to get the value of `private` `static` field `myString` of a class `Program`, in another class `DoStuff`. If this is what you are trying to do, this is what you need in the `DoStuff` class (you can very much write the whole statement in one line)

```
using System;

public class DoStuff
{
    public static void ShowVariable()
    {
        var type = typeof(Program); //get type of Program
        //get the field, which is static and private
        var field = type.GetField("myString", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var val = field.GetValue(null); //field value, null - as the field doesn't belong to an instance

        Console.WriteLine(val);
    }
}
```